# Replace \n\r in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, character-encoding

How can I replace `\n\r` in fields inside my database with a new line?
This data was from a previous table which has the column type set wrong.

Comment: I think you're thinking `\r\n`  - the carriage return + newline common on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE(`column`, '\\r\\n', '\r\n');
```

nevertheless do a backup before you try!

You might want to replace single occurrences after that too:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE(`column`, '\\n', '\n');
UPDATE `table` SET `column` = REPLACE(`column`, '\\r', '\r');
```

Since not all OS use `\r\n` as combination for line breaks.

Comment: Are those backticks really usefull in your query?

Comment: @Fabio They escape the tablename and columnname. Since I used `table` and `column` as example names, which are reserved keywords otherwise, I decided to wrap them in backticks to make the query executable. I could have used other names for the example though...

Comment: @FelipeMorales If you have a specific case you cannot apply this solution too, feel free to ask a new question and describe your problem in detail. This solution surely solved the problem asked in this question.

Comment: https://gfycat.com/ScholarlyQuestionableKitfox the question is general, as the response and my issue, doesn't seems to work anymore

Comment: You may have different data inside your table. Please provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/ with your specific data and open a new question. The screencast does not help.